# Куда девается значок программы в панели задач?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Вот какой вопрос. Создал программу с двумя окнами. При работе программы открывается первое окно, затем если нажать на кнопку на этом окне, то открывается другое окно. Вроде ничего необычного. Первая проблема: после того, как открылось второе окно пропадает значок программы на панели задач. Как сделать чтобы он сохранился? И как раз из-за этой проблемы, второе окно не сворачивается нормально. Тупо просто в угол рабочего стола уходит. В чем дело?
Например вот такой код:
Первое окно:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window_1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 146)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 221, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нажми"))
```

Второе окно:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window_2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(290, 143)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 171, 71))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Тут что-то написано"))
```

И главное которое запускает:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

from Window1 import Window_1
from Window2 import Window_2

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Win = Window_1()
        self.Win.setupUi(self)
        self.Win.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check)

    def check(self):
        des = Window2(parent=self)
        self.hide()

class Window2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Win_2 = Window_2()
        self.Win_2.setupUi(self)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пробовали брать не `QMainWindow` а `QWidget`? 1 ваша проблема в том что вы сами скрываете окно `Window` путем функции `self.hide()` вы можете его обратно вернуть путем функции `self.setVisible(True)` 2-я проблема не совсем понятна потому что при использовании вашего кода у меня лично все отлично сворачивается и работает корректно

Comment: Если поставить QWidget, то программа вообще не работает. Проблема именно во втором окне.

Comment: @Twiss `self.setVisible(True)` -> `self.show()` :D

Comment: @gil9red ну я не виноват что `self.hold()` == `self.setVisible(False)` == `self.close()`, а `self.setVisible(True)` == `self.show()` :D

Comment: Проблема решена, вот что главное)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените:

```
self.des = Window2()
```

На:

```
des = Window2(parent=self)
```

---

Дело в том, что у объекта-виджета не было связи с каким-либо объектом, поэтому после завершения функции он был удален. А `self.des` привязывает объект, что защищает его от уничтожения.

Кст, правильно будет сделать так (нет смысла создавать каждый раз виджет):

```
...

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.Win = Window_1()
        self.Win.setupUi(self)
        self.Win.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check)
        self.des = Window2()

    def check(self):
        self.des.show()
        self.hide()


class Window2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.Win_2 = Window_2()
        self.Win_2.setupUi(self)
```

Comment: Уже не первый раз помогаете. Спасибо, помогло)